# What is the time complexity of this problem?

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity

Let's say I have a code like this,

```
def func1(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
         # something in here
    return some_val
```

What would be time complexity in this case? Is it O(n) because of the for loop? I have a sorted function of O(n*log(n)) before the loop is called on the sorted input list. In this case what would be total time complexity of the whole problem?

Comment: Depends on what `something` is in there

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that something inside the for loop is some expression of O(1) time.

Answer (score 2):

Here the time complexity will be O(n*log(n)). The loop runs in linear time, O(n). The O(n*log(n)) sorting operation is the more expensive operation. Since the sorting and the loop are done sequentially one after the other, the most expensive operation determines the Big-O of the function.
This is assuming `# something in here` is a O(1) operation.

Comment: So the algorithm has O(n*log(n)) sort function and a for loop of O(n), time complexity for the whole problem according to Big-O definition is O(n*log(n)). Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

```py
def func1(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr) // Here O(n*log(n))
    for i in range(len(arr)): // Your loop O(n)
         # something in here
    return some_val
```

Based on your code the total time complexity O(n*log(n)) + O(n) since the growth of the log-linear function is higher than linear function then we can omit O(n). The final complexity will be O(n*log(n))